# React Apollo - How to make multiple queries in a single pollInterval

Tags: javascript, graphql, react-apollo

I have multiple queries that I want to fetch after each 10 seconds, I can fetch the queries like this:

```
compose(
  graphql(QUERY_1, {
    options: {
      pollInterval: 10000
    }
  }),
  graphql(QUERY_2, {
    options: {
      pollInterval: 10000
    }
  }),
  ....
)
```

but that would make more than one intervals which I don't want. Is there any way in `react-apollo` to make multiple queries under a single interval. For example something like this:

```
compose(
  graphql([QUERY_1, QUERY_2],
    options: { pollInterval: 10000 }
  ),
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it for now is combine multiple queries in one e.g.

```
const QUERIES_GROUP = gql`
  {
    QUERY_1 ...,
    QUERY_2 ...
  }
`
compose(
  graphql(QUERIES_GROUP, {
    options: { pollInterval: 10000 }
  })
)
```

The disadvantage of using above approach is that we cannot reuse query `QUERY_1` or `QUERY_2` in some other component

Another option is to use batching https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/batch-http.html